# Trying to figure out SQL Statement

Tags: sql

I need to know what this statement is doing:

```
DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, startdate), 0)
```

Would appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [DATEADD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) and [DATEDIFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)?

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: I did look at the doc couldn't understand it, that's why I posted it here, why everyone is so negative, some people don't pick up things like others

Comment: After adding that line the time still shows up, am I doing something wrong? DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, startdate), 0)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it would have been far easier to just lookup the answer in the docs than to ask for it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) for `DATEDIFF()`:

> Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.

So this

```
DATEDIFF(dd, 0, startdate)
```

returns the number of days passed between date 0 and the value in your column startdate. `Select` above function and replace `startdate` with `GETDATE()` (the current date and time). 
When you divide the returned value through 365 you will get something like 114. Current year - 214 = 1900. So the date "`0`" seems to be `1900-01-01 00:00:00`.

From the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) for `DATEADD()`:

> Returns a specified date with the specified number interval (signed integer) added to a specified datepart of that date.

Now when you add this value to the date "`0`" again, you get the current date, because only the number of days were added to `1900-01-01 00:00:00`.

The time value was stripped from the datetime value.

Comment: Explained it well, I did look at the doc but couldn't make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

It's stripping off the time component of a datetime